# How to insert a sleep/pause before the next method is called in android?

Tags: android

In an android app I have a layout, and when the user presses a button a different layout is shown (in the same activity). But instead to show the different layout right away, I want to put in a small delay (ca. 0.5 seconds). How to do that best in android?

In python you just do `time.sleep(0.5)` but I have seen already dozen of code lines to do the same. How to do this the *most simple way as possible*?

Comment: If android were single-threaded, `Thread.sleep()` is it, but that would lock the UI and crash the app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void onClick(View v) {
  v.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      // do your delayed work
    }
  }, DELAY_PERIOD);
}
```

where `DELAY_PERIOD` is the delay period in milliseconds. Here, `onClick()` is in your `OnClickListener` implementation, or is the method pointed to by `android:onClick` in your layout, or is pointed to by the data binding framework.

Comment: I have no idea why this is that complicated, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

There is Thread.sleep(timeInMs) but it is not the best option because it will suspend the main (ui thread).

It would be better to use [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        someAction();
    }
}, 500)
```

Comment: [Be careful when creating instances of `Handler` like that](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html).

Comment: yes, of course, it is usually created as class member. Also if you submit long actions with long delay, you should consider of canceling them with `removeCallbacksAndMessages` to prevent from activity leaks.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is to use a Handler:

```
import android.os.Handler;

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do something
    }
}, 500);
```

Comment: While I think a downvote is a bit harsh (for whoever did that), [be careful when creating instances of `Handler` like that](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html).

Comment: @CommonsWare, I read the article & your answer above. I still don't understand what is the real difference between the 2 implementations. According to the documentations View.postDelayed() "Causes the Runnable to be added to the message queue, to be run after the specified amount of time elapses. The runnable will be run on the user interface thread." This means that your implementation (in particular, your Runnable) would also leak the activity for 10 seconds. This is all true unless the Handler behaves differently than the View.

Comment: In this specific case, the use of `Handler` may be comparable to calling `postDelayed()` directly on the `View`. However, in general, creating instances of `Handler` requires care. In cases where there is an equivalent non-`Handler` solution (e.g., calling `postDelayed()` on the `View`), I recommend the non-`Handler` solution, just so that people do not get into the habit of just creating `Handler` instances whenever it suits them. That's one of the reasons why we wrap `Handler` objects in other things (e.g., `AsyncTask`), and it's why Lint will complain about your code.

Comment: I think the only solution here is to cancel the request when the activity... otherwise the solutions are the same (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41728973/what-is-the-difference-between-view-postdelayed-and-handler-postdelayed-on-t). -1 for the downvote...