# What is the difference between View.postDelayed() and Handler.postDelayed() on the main thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-handler

According to the documentation of `Handler.postDelayed(Runnable r, long delayMillis)`:

> Causes the Runnable r to be added to the message queue, to be run
>   after the specified amount of time elapses. The runnable will be run
>   on the thread to which this handler is attached.

On the other hand `View.postDelayed(Runnable action, long delayMillis)`:

> Causes the Runnable to be added to the message queue, to be run after
>   the specified amount of time elapses. The runnable will be run on the
>   user interface thread.

I want to know if there is a difference between the two while calling them from the main thread and in particular, if there is a difference when the activity is being destroyed?

I have read this [article](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html) about how I might leak an Activity when I use an inner class Handler and I was wondering whether using `View.postDelayed()` would cause the same problem.

For example could foo() cause an issue or would the destruction of the activity solve the fact that the `Runnable` anonymous class is holding a reference to the activity?

```
public class MyActiviy extends Activity {
    private void foo(View v) {
        v.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // some delayed work
            }
        }, 60000);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the source, `View.postDelayed()` is simply using `Handler.postDelayed()` on an internal handler so there is no difference.

`foo()` may leak the Activity, you should use `View.removeCallbacks()` to minimize this chance.

Comment: Please provide the link for the source.

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/a175a5b/core/java/android/view/View.java#8733

Comment: Now you can use lambdas. In that case foo() wont leak the Activity

Comment: @RavjitSingh  Could you provide an example?