# Which approach is better for custom View: creating new Handler or using existing one?

Tags: android, view, handler, android-custom-view, postdelayed

Lately, I was writing a custom `View` in my Android app, by extending the `View` class. I needed some looping animation inside and I used `new Handler().postDelayed(...)` to set a delay between loops. One of my colleagues told me that I don't need to create a new instance of `Handler` since `View` already has it, I just needed to call `postDelayed(...)`. This approach seems legit, however, I got suspicious, whether this is a good practice, perhaps it may break something?

I'd like to hear the difference between these approaches, why `View` has integrated this method `postDelayed()` and **IS IT REALLY THE SAME THING** to use this method instead of creating new `Handler` instance and calling `postDelayed()` on it?

Comment: Have you checked this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41728973/what-is-the-difference-between-view-postdelayed-and-handler-postdelayed-on-t

Comment: @NovoLucas Yes, of course, however it doesn't answer my question, I don't ask for difference, more for the better approach here. Also, that question has only 1 answer, which I found insufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The handler is provided by `AttachInfo` Object. It is a final class in the View. Contains a lot of information about the view.

```
    /**
     * A Handler supplied by a view's {@link android.view.ViewRootImpl}. This
     * handler can be used to pump events in the UI events queue.
     */
    final Handler mHandler;
```

You can check the View class Documentation

And yes, you can use it rather than creating your own.

Comment: Exactly what your colleague said